# What kind of property should be set to nil in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC. Will ARC automatically release all the properties in `dealloc`? Is it necessary to manual set all public properties and private field to `nil`? Are there any good pattern to follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under ARC, the pattern is... don't do anything in dealloc, or even implement it. ARC takes care of your properties and instance variables for you.

The only exception is that dealloc is a good place to unregister for notifications, if your object has registered for any.

Comment: Unegistering notifications in dealloc is very important, because this kind of bugs are very hard to find

Comment: If any objecs have any delegates, the delegates can be nil-ed here too . `someObject.delegate = nil;`

Comment: @GangstaGraham if the objects have weak references to their delegates, you shouldn't need to do this, but I have found on occasion that it has to be done, particularly for scroll view and web view delegates, even under ARC.

Comment: Note that if you are targeting iOS 9 and later or OS X 10.11 then you also no longer need to unregister for notifications (unless they are block based) as that will also be handled by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. When using `ARC` the compiler will implement a `dealloc` method for you and will handle implicitly the release of your instance variables and properties.

You may still need a custom -`dealloc` if your class needs to do anything other than releasing memory (e.g unregister for notifications like jrturton mentioned).

You can get a good grasp of what's you need to consider when transitioning to ARC in those Apple official [notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11).